# Layout in Hot Towel SPA with top and navigation sidebars

Tags: knockout.js, navigation, single-page-application, hottowel

I want to start a new SPA application, and I found Hot Towel template very interesting

I need to have two navigation areas - left panel and top panel.

But Hot towel's default shell contains only three areas - header, footer and content

```
<div>
  <header>
    <!--ko compose: {view: 'nav'} --><!--/ko-->
  </header>
  <section id="content" class="main container-fluid">
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose, 
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!--/ko-->
  </section>
  <footer>
    <!--ko compose: {view: 'footer'} --><!--/ko-->
  </footer>
</div>
```

How can I add a new area, leftnav?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I understand how durandal works with sub-views

Any view can import any number of subviews, and the layout is simply a matter of hw we design the and style the divs with CSS

To include a left nav, all that has to be done is to add a new `<!--ko ... -->` tag, and make sure it has proper css class / style to be rendered as left nav

Something like this

```
<!--ko compose: {view: 'top-nav'} --><!--/ko--> 
<!--ko compose: {view: 'left-nav'} --><!--/ko--> 
<!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
    afterCompose: router.afterCompose, 
    transition: 'entrance'} -->
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko compose: {view: 'footer'} --><!--/ko-->
```

Th additional tags, like `<header>`, `<section>`, etc are not even needed, they can simply be top tags in the sub-views (or it works very well without, depending on one's preferences)

From this point, it's all a matter on how we define the actual views nop-nav, left-nav, etc